# Cannot resize image captured with CameraX?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, image-compression, android-camerax, resize-image

I've succesfully capture image with CameraX into JPEG files. The problem is the file size is big. On an Android powered walki talkie (Android 11), the result is typically 4 to 6 MB, so I'd like to resize it.

Here's my code:

```
fun takePhoto() {
        val FILENAME_FORMAT = "ddMMyyyy_HHmmss"

        val capturedContentValues = ContentValues()
        capturedContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            "CARAKA_"+SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        capturedContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/TESTAPP")
        capturedContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")

        val outputOptions= ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
            context.contentResolver,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            capturedContentValues
        ).build()


        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val theFile = getFile(context, output.savedUri!!)
                    val capturedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(theFile!!.absolutePath)
                    val resizedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(capturedBitmap, 1024)
                    val fout = FileOutputStream(theFile.absolutePath)
                    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout)

                    fout.flush()
                    fout.close()

                }
            })
    }

    fun getResizedBitmap(image: Bitmap, maxSize: Int): Bitmap {
        var width = image.width
        var height = image.height
        val bitmapRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize
            height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
        } else {
            height = maxSize
            width = (height * bitmapRatio).toInt()
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true)
    }
 
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun getFile(context: Context, uri: Uri): File? {
        val destinationFilename =
            File(context.filesDir.path + File.separatorChar + queryName(context, uri))
        try {
            context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { ins ->
                createFileFromStream(
                    ins!!,
                    destinationFilename
                )
            }
        } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
            Log.e("Save File", ex.message!!)
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return destinationFilename
    }

    fun createFileFromStream(ins: InputStream, destination: File?) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream(destination).use { os ->
                val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
                var length: Int
                while (ins.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length)
                }
                os.flush()
            }
        } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
            Log.e("Save File", ex.message!!)
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun queryName(context: Context, uri: Uri): String {
        val returnCursor: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)!!
        val nameIndex: Int = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        returnCursor.moveToFirst()
        val name: String = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
        returnCursor.close()
        return name
    }
```

Those saved JPEGs size is still within 4 to 6 MB. Not reduced into hundreds KB. What's wrong here?

Comment: Please tell original resolution. Also tell final resolution.

Comment: Size: 2.4 MB. Resolution: 2448 × 3264 (both before and after image resize/compression). I'm sure the bitmap resize/compression code isn't correct.

Comment: I agree. But not while compressing. Well debug. Log every width and height. Asd remove the functions from your post you did not use.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of resizing it afterwards, another thing you can try is taking a smaller picture. You can set the target resolution to be lower: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.Builder#setTargetResolution(android.util.Size)